# can i have password for my mysql table

Tags: mysql, database-design

is there a way i can set password on a table i am creating in mysql. i am working with rather sensitive data , and i have to use mysql on a server on which i am obviously not the admin. so people using mysql on that server can pretty much see the tables other users are creating. is there a way i can make a table which requires a password to access the particular table, if not can anyone suggest another alternative. admin has not given rights to create a new database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way to access a table created by you using additional username/password for a user once he logged in. One can control access by a normal MySQL login. The username used for that can be configured to have only access to the objects you want by setting up privileges. So the username decides what is allowed and what is not.